# Ajax call bring the user back to same page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a search page done using Laravel. On that page there is a button which makes an AJAX call to another url. That page is paginated, so the user can be on the first, second or last page.

My problem is, How can I bring the user back to the same page and point that he was.

Or, Is there a way to just call a method to perform some actions on the database?

Thats my Ajax Call:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
                dataType: 'html',
                success:function(data) {
                        $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
                        $.growl.notice({ title: 'Voto', message: 'Computado com sucesso' });
                        $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
                        }
        });
```

I know if i take the $('#ajaxResponse').html(data); bit it is going to perform the change but not update the numbers that i need. Any ideas?

Comment: How is that called? As part of an on click?

Comment: yes, that is it

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#converting-results-to-json) for pagination in Laravel with JSON. As you can see, when you paginate your data, the resulting JSON object will contain information about the next and previous pages. Update the links your users click with the provided information and they should see the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the actual page in a session key and use a controller to check this key and display the page that you want. In this case you can keep your ajax call as it is and change only your laravel controller ad view.